# how can we upload folder in s3 using file picker used html javascript

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-s3

how can we upload the folder directly in s3 server using html JavaScript

```
<form action="https://spreedemostore.s3.amazonaws.com/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" name="key" value="${filename}">
  <input type="hidden" name="AWSAccessKeyId" value= "AKIAIDSTEOFIIVTWCUFA" > 
  <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="public-read"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="success_action_status" value="201">
  <input type="hidden" name="policy" value= "eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjoiMjAxNC0xMC0xM1QxODoyMzoxNFoiLCJjb25kaXRpb25zIjpbeyJidWNrZXQiOiJzcHJlZWRlbW9zdG9yZSJ9LHsiYWNsIjoicHVibGljLXJlYWQifSxbInN0YXJ0cy13aXRoIiwiJGtleSIsIiJdLHsic3VjY2Vzc19hY3Rpb25fc3RhdHVzIjoiMjAxIn1dfQ==" >
  <input type="hidden" name="signature" value= "lsspLDjPbE6UL+/28bs0oOWZ82g=" >
  <!-- Include any additional input fields here -->

  File to upload to S3: 
  <input name="file" type="file"> 
  <br> 
  <input type="submit" value="Upload File to S3"> 
</form>
```

Check - i try to upload folder not file but its not happening can u help me out how to upload the folder directly in amazon s3 server
[Click](https://jsfiddle.net/soniii/nmh2jaL8/1/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upload folder and all its content in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239663/upload-folder-and-all-its-content-in-javascript)

Comment: how to upload entire folder in s3 server https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239663/upload-folder-and-all-its-content-in-javascript    this one is not upload in amazon s3 server.i want to upload folder in server s3

Comment: The receiver of the data isn't important at all. You should specify the actuals problems you faced and what you tried to overcome then in your questions.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soniii/nmh2jaL8/1/  in here i try to upload folder in s3 but when i clck on upload button file is not uploaded in s3 server actually. thats my question