# Is there any way to upload folder using node js Multer?

Tags: node.js, express, react-dropzone

Instead of uploading zip file, I want to upload a folder through `react-dropzone`. Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: It is not an efficient way to do so, you can create an API end point and unzip before uploading it.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara ,ok I want try this as experiment , this motivates me [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826286/how-do-i-use-google-chrome-11s-upload-folder-feature-in-my-own-code)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239663/upload-folder-and-all-its-content-in-javascript) sense?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara,Thank you ,it helped me.