# Django : upload direct folder to input type file instead selecting multiple files

Tags: python, django

How can we upload direct folder to input type file ?
I mean user can upload direct folder of images or files instead of selecting multiple files?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

that's a javascript question

```
<div class="picker"><input type="file" id="picker" name="fileList" webkitdirectory multiple></div>
let picker = document.getElementById('picker');
picker.addEventListener('change', e => {
  for (let file of Array.from(e.target.files)) {
   //now append files to formdata
  };
});
```

found this on previous question  [Upload folder and all its content in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239663/upload-folder-and-all-its-content-in-javascript)